# Cannot kill process that is blocking port 8080

Tags: windows-10, process

I'm trying to kill a process that is using port 8080 on my local machine. But when I try, Windows tells me Access Denied. I looked a the process using Process Explorer and I see it's the System process. The process tree includes smss.exe. But all attempts to kill these give me access denied.

I'm able to use that port on the computer at work. But at home, this port is used.
Is there any way to get out of this? I have no choice but to use 8080 for a local web service.

I stopped IIS just in case. But that did not work.

Comment: If it's `smss` then that's probably SQL Server Management Studio -- have you tried stopping that service? Shouldn't be part of `System` though. What does `netstat -abn -p tcp` tell you?

Comment: I usually use (in powershell as admin) `netstat -abno | findstr LISTENING` and note the PID for the port. Then I use `tasklist | findstr <thePID>` to isolate the process. Last time I had a conflict on 8080/8081, it was McAffe Enterprise Management services.